# How to enable xhr on http requests to express.js using postman

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I am trying to enable xhr on express.js req.xhr via postman requests. I know that I have to put something inside header of request, but I don't know what!

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are well. By looking at the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.xhr), in order for `req.xhr` to be populated you need to send an xhr request (can also be done using fetch etc) and you need to set the `X-Requested-With` header with the value `XMLHttpRequest`.